# How to find out checkbox group in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

My HTML form contains many checkbox groups,I want to check if atleast one checkbox is selected from every group.

For example

```
// Group vehicle
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"/> I have a bike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"/> I have a car <br/>   

// Group language
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="JS"/> I am JS Ninja <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="Android"/> I am a droid <br/>
```

I can use following Jquery selector to check if at least one checkbox is selected

```
if($(":checkbox:checked[vehicle]").length) > 1
if($(":checkbox:checked[language]").length) > 1
```

But I have to repeat this selector for every checkbox group. My page contains many checkbox groups. Is there any other way by which I can select all checkbox groups in single jquery selector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated as promised, once I had the time to fully test the original example code. I see you guys went a little overboard, it only needed some minor adjustments to function :D

I also made it a bit more efficient by not repeating the jQuery checkbox selectors multiple times.

And the result:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkedTest() {
            var nameArr = new Array();
            var finalResult = true;
            var allCheckboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");

            // Put all the unique name attributes in an array.
            allCheckboxes.each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                if($.inArray(name, nameArr) == -1)
                    nameArr.push(name);
            });

            // Go through each name attribue and make sure at least one is checked.
            $.each(nameArr, function(index, value){
                if(allCheckboxes.filter("[name=" + value + "]:checked").length == 0)
                    finalResult = false;
            });

            return finalResult;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Group1Box1: <input type="checkbox" id="group1Box1" name="group1"/>
    Group1Box2: <input type="checkbox" id="group1Box2" name="group1"/>
    <br/>
    Group2Box1: <input type="checkbox" id="group2Box1" name="group2"/>
    Group2Box2: <input type="checkbox" id="group2Box2" name="group2"/>
    <br/>
    Group3Box1: <input type="checkbox" id="group3Box1" name="group3"/>
    Group3Box2: <input type="checkbox" id="group3Box2" name="group3"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Test!" onclick="alert(checkedTest());"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could optimize a few things there. Haven't tried but I guess it works by the upvote.

Comment: @elclanrs Absolute, that's why I gave the disclaimer at the top. It's not meant as a direct copy paste but illustrates a solution to the problem that can be adapted.

Comment: @elclanrs: Wondering if we have anything in Jquery selector which can be used instead?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I was trying to work on a solution but I got lost, lol.

Comment: @elclanrs: I mean instead of populating array with distinct names, can we write a Jquery selector which will do the same? I am not sure if we have such thing in Jquery.

Comment: @b1naryj: Something is wrong with `$.inArray($(this).attr("name")) == -1` , getting error `Error: can't convert undefined to object` . I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DMdLQ/3/

Comment: @Ajinkya I have updated my solution as promised now that I had time to fully test the example code. It only needed very minor tweaks to function.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the logic seemed correct I couldn't make **b1naryj's** solution work.
I continued working on it from his example and finally got it working:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/1/

**jQ:**

```
var testCheckboxes = function(){
    var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox'),
        names = [],
        num = 0;
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($.inArray(name, names) === -1) {
            names.push(name);
        }
    });
    $.each(names, function(i, v){
        if ($checkboxes.filter('[name="'+v+'"]:checked').length >= 1) { num++; }
    });
    if (num === names.length) { alert('Yup!'); }
};
```

Comment: I have edited **b1naryjs** answer. Its working I guess. Have a look.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't make it work. I noticed the jsfiddle I posted didn't work. I updated it.

Comment: There was a problem with `inArray($(this).attr("name"),nameArr`. Check my edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9287311/revisions

Comment: @elclanrs My original "example" code was actually pretty close considering no testing. I've since updated the original solution once I had time to fully test.

Answer (score 0):

```
// If you know the names just setting its here like var names = ["vehicle","language"]
var names = [];
// Find out the checkbox group names
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
  names.push(this.name);
});
names = $.unique(names);

var pass = true;
$.each(names, function(){
  if(!pass) return;
  pass = !!$("[name=" + this + "]:checkbox:checked").length;
});
alert("Pass? " + pass);
```

Checkout [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mRB4k/1/)

Answer (score -3):

I think this will work for you:

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var vehicles= $("input[name='vehicle']").serializeArray(); 
      alert(vehicles.length + ' vehicles selected.');
    var languages = $("input[name='language']").serializeArray(); 
    alert(languages .length + ' languages  selected.');
});
```

You can then check the length of chkbx. Here's how you can use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/WTudu/5/

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. He wants to grab all checkboxes and check if each group has at least one selected.

Comment: How does this not? This will grab per group as his example indicates his grouping. Check the jsfiddle for proof....

Comment: Just put the stuff from the fiddle into the post. That single line of code, out of context, is meaningless in this situation. Your implementation seems to work great, so people would rather see what works right off the bat than a preview.

Comment: Not sure how it was meaningless, as it did exactly what he wanted--a way of getting he number of checkboxes checked in a grouping. Nonetheless, I've brought over the example.

Comment: I think the point is he doesn't want to have to put the name attribute. He simply wants to check all checkboxes from the page per group and see if it has at least one checked per group. I could be wrong but that's what I understand. Btw I didn't downvote.

Comment: @OnResolve: Even code I mentioned in question is working but I want to avoid it and trying to write a generic code.

Comment: Yet the other answer with using name as well is upvoted one. Can't win 'em all I guess. Good luck...